# get apache version on which a website is running

Tags: apache, browser

for my internship, I have to read in XML files and edit them. these XML files are hosted on their server and I have to upload tar.7z files to get access to them. however, when I upload them I get a 403 forbidden error. my supervisor thinks it is because I am running a newer version of apache than the website to which I need to send it. is there any command I can put into the website console to check the version?

Comment: Can you give some logs and reformat a bit your question to make it easier to read?

Comment: @MarcLeBihan I sadly don't have any logs. it is an external server that I have to upload my files to but I can't ask for any information. all I have is the 403 error and the page on which that error shows up.